# Not able to open unsafe site even after using openBrowser({ignoreCertificateErrors: true}) in Taiko

Tags: javascript, selenium, ssl-certificate, chromium, taiko

The below site has a browser popup authentication, so I tried the following code.

> https://e.clinique.na.us.rac-166-dec22-elb3.ncsastage.usva1.feature.elco.cloud/

```
openBrowser({ignoreCertificateErrors: true}); goto('https://feature:bb#Yrp$!xNP6@e.clinique.na.us.rac-166-dec22-elb3.ncsastage.usva1.feature.elco.cloud/')
```

[image]

with following syntax

> https://username:password@url

But I am getting errors as Invalid URL for the above code mentioned.

Attached is the ScreenShot of the error
[image: The actual error]

[image: The error on using .trace]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please visit the following discussion from GitHub

> https://github.com/getgauge/taiko/discussions/2463